# Where can I find spectral data for materials?

Tags: resource-recommendations, physical-chemistry, spectroscopy

The chemical library of [ChemSpider](http://www.chemspider.com/) has a dedicated section for spectra, but I haven't found any materials that have such data. Is there a (public) database of spectral data?

Comment: Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic, this is clearly a spectroscopy question, under the spectroscopy tag of this community...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89450/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in **molecules** then

The nist webbook has a huge store of information ---- see

http://webbook.nist.gov     (NB no pay wall)

You can search pretty easily and get mass spectra, heats of formation and some information about IR and UV/Vis spectra as well

To quote from their front page there are....

- Thermochemical data for over 7000 organic and small inorganic compounds:
- Reaction thermochemistry data for over 8000 reactions.
- IR spectra for over 16,000 compounds.
- Mass spectra for over 33,000 compounds.
- UV/Vis spectra for over 1600 compounds.
- Gas chromatography data for over 27,000 compounds.
- Electronic and vibrational spectra for over 5000 compounds.
- Constants of diatomic molecules (spectroscopic data) for over 600 compounds.
- Ion energetics data for over 16,000 compounds:

If you are interested in **solid state materials** then you may need to look elsewhere....

The way to use the NIST Chemistry Webbook is to put in the formula of the molecule you are interested in and then it will show you what resources are available for that molecule. Formulae can be enetered from [this page](http://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/form-ser.html)

Comment: @Sparkler try http://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/ does that help - put the molecule in the formula search and you take it from there

Comment: Some note-worthy index pages I've found: [XPS data for all elements](http://srdata.nist.gov/xps/all_dat_el.aspx); [Quantitative Infrared Database](http://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/quant-ir/) and [THz Spectral Database](http://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/thz-ir/).

Comment: @Sparkler - you could put these links in an answer of your own - it is ok to answer your own question... as well

Answer (score 0):

Some note-worthy index pages for spectal data:

- XPS data for all elements: [in a periodic table format](http://srdata.nist.gov/xps/all_dat_el.aspx)
- [Quantitative Infrared Database](http://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/quant-ir/)
- [THz Spectral Database](http://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/thz-ir/)
- [X-ray properties of elements](http://xdb.lbl.gov/Section1/) (also [in a periodic table format](http://xdb.lbl.gov/Section1/Periodic_Table/X-ray_Elements.html))